# View Div When A Hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a strip with pictures that I want to hover over them,and text pops beneath the picture with what the picture is.

I think there is a problem with the CSS. And if you can do it maybe try to get the transition to work too.

Here is the CSS and HTML :

```css
.procat{
    background-color: #555555;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.procat img{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.procath{
    display: none;
    transition: 1s;
}
.procath a.procath:hover{
    display: block;
    transition: 1s;
    background-color:dimgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="procat">
                <a class="tb" href="ThunderBird">
                    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="pic/icons/phone.png">
                </a>
                <a href="ZeroBook">
                    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="pic/icons/laptop.png">
                </a>
                <a href="ProjectTime">
                    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="pic/icons/car.png">
                </a>
                <div class="procath">
                    <h6>
                        ThunderBird
                    </h6>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: you want to show the div that has the header with content "ThunderBird" when any images is hovered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display` property can't be transitioned. Use `visibility` instead and also use proper selectors. This link should explain more about affecting other elements on hover: [How to affect other elements when a div is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)

Also, solution below

```css
.procat{
    background-color: #555555;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.procat img{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.procath{
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 1s;
}
.procat a:hover ~ .procath{
    visibility:visible;
    transition: 1s;
    background-color:dimgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="procat">
                <a class="tb" href="ThunderBird">
                    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="pic/icons/phone.png">
                </a>
                <a href="ZeroBook">
                    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="pic/icons/laptop.png">
                </a>
                <a href="ProjectTime">
                    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="pic/icons/car.png">
                </a>
                <div class="procath">
                    <h6>
                        ThunderBird
                    </h6>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: FWIW `visibility` and `display` are different, not-quite-interchangeable properties with different applications; `visibility` means that the element takes up layout space either way (it's almost the same as just using `opacity`, which would transition more smoothly IMO). This is one of those simple problems that always ends up with a more complicated solution.

Comment: @BenSaufley That's true, I assumed that OP doesn't know that `display` can't be triggered by `transition`, hence I offered a solution using `visibility`.  The only way of doing it while still using `display` would be using JavaScript.